# Opening CRM entity doesn't display any records in both Outlook 2013 and 2010 with integrated CRM Client 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-2010, outlook-2013, crm-outlook-client

Opening CRM entity doesn't display any records in both Outlook 2013 and 2010 with integrated CRM Client 2011 as shown in the picture.
[image]

I have done following work but all in vain.

1) Open Diagnostic from Start Menu

- Enabled Tracing
- Disabled Cache
- Reset Add On's

2) Go to Options in Outlook. Then Add On's.
Both of the Microsoft CRM addin's were already checked in

3) Went to Internet Options in Internet Explorer Setting. I was unable to find any CRM add'on there
[image]